# In a codrova/phonegap based Xcode project, how do i turn my single view app into a multiple view app?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have set up Cordova/phonegap to work in Xcode and written a simple app in HTML and CSS and tested it on the Simulator and it works. It's just a single view app. I am trying to figure out how to turn that into a multiple view app, so that there are several views/screens that link to each other.

Do I need to write several HTML documents and link them together in XCode, or is it written in one HTML document using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

With PhoneGap, think of it as operating a tiny web server on your device. So, you build it out like you would any other web site - with links to other pages that sit in that folder/directory or even on other servers - and it will allow that navigation. So, once you get it set up and deployed via Xcode, all you need to do is modify the html/css/js.